# use two primary keys attribute from a table with different title

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I got table "Functions" with Function_ID {PK} and I want another table "Hierarchy" with Hierarchy_ID {PK} which defines tree structure of functions so i need one Function_ID from Function table AS Parent_ID and one Function_ID AS Child. my question is how i can use two primary keys from another table to make it together as Foreign key

I am using SQL Server 2012 and the Management Studio

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need to add a ParentFunction_ID column in the Functions table.
You don't need another table if your structure is indeed a tree.
Then make the ParentFunction_ID to be a FK to the same table Functions.
So ParentFunction_ID (FK) would be pointing to Function_ID (PK).
The only record which has ParentFunction_ID NULL would be the root of your tree.

Here is some sample code:

```
USE [test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Functions](
    [Function_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FunctionCode] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ParentFunction_ID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Functions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Function_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Functions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Functions_Functions] FOREIGN KEY([ParentFunction_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Functions] ([Function_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Functions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Functions_Functions]
GO
```

Comment: the reason why i have separate table because for one function i will have possibly multiple combinations

Comment: OK, added another answer which is based on your recent input that this is not really a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Name your **Functions** table a **Function** table. AFAIK using 
plurals for table names is not really a good practice.

So you can do this.

```
--- 1 ---    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Function](
    [Function_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FunctionCode] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Function] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Function_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO




--- 2 ---
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hierarchy](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentFunction_ID] [int] NULL,
    [ChildFunction_ID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Hierarchy] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Hierarchy]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Hierarchy_Function] FOREIGN KEY([ParentFunction_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Function] ([Function_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Hierarchy] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Hierarchy_Function]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Hierarchy]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Hierarchy_Function1] FOREIGN KEY([ChildFunction_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Function] ([Function_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Hierarchy] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Hierarchy_Function1]
GO
```